# How to define point cuts for a sequence of method(s)?

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

For example if I have 3 classes,

```
class A {
    public void doA() {
        /* do something */
    }
}

class B {
    public void doB() {
        A a = new A();
        a.doA();
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B();
        b.doB();
    }
}
```

Now I want to define a point cut for flow doB() -> doA(), like if doB() calls doA() grab parameters from class A and class B and do something in aspect method. Could someone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me slightly extend your sample code in order to make you understand what my solution does and what it cannot do:

```java
class A {
    public void doA() {}
}
```

```java
class B {
    public void doB() {
        new A().doA();
        new C().doC();
    }
}
```

```java
class C {
    public void doC() {
        new A().doA();
    }
}
```

```java
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new A().doA();      // should not be captured
        new B().doB();      // should be captured
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a new class `C` now and we have three control flows now:

- `MyClass.main -> A.doA`
- `MyClass.main -> B.doB -> A.doA`
- `MyClass.main -> B.doB -> C.doC -> A.doA`

You want to exclude #1 and capture #2, but what about #3? In this case `a.doA` is called *indirectly* from `B.doB` via `C.doC`. My solution also captures this indirect case. If this is fine for you or it does not happen in your code base, you can use my solution. Otherwise things would get a little more complicated and you would need to inspect the call stack. Tell me if you need to exclude #2, and I will extend my answer, but the solution will not look as simple as this one, I can promise.

Now here is the aspect:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class ControlFlowInterceptor {
    @Before("execution(void A.doA()) && target(a) && cflow(execution(void B.doB()) && target(b))")
    public void advice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, A a, B b) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("  " + a);
        System.out.println("  " + b);
    }
}
```

The console output looks like this:

```
execution(void A.doA())
  A@7b19f779
  B@65c66812
execution(void A.doA())
  A@4df2868
  B@65c66812
```

Please note that we have the same `B` object ID in both outputs, but because `C.doC` creates an new `A` object, we have two different `A` object IDs.

Comment: Thank you @kriegaex, this is what I have been looking for :-)